# Remove everything after a character, but keep the character

Tags: r, regex

Let's say I have a string that reads `"45216 Walnut Avenue Mary's Bake Shop"`. 
I want to remove everything after the word `Avenue`, but I would like avenue to remain. How does this work?

I've tried the following with no luck:

```
a <- "45216 Walnut Avenue Mary's Bake Shop"
a <- gsub("Avenue.*$", "", a)

[1] "45216 Walnut "
```

Comment: Are you wondering if r regex has a negative look behind?

Comment: Use `a <- gsub("Avenue.*$", "Avenue", a)`

Comment: or `gsub("(?<=Avenue).*$", "", a, perl = TRUE)`

Comment: or `gsub("(.*Avenue)|.", "\\1", a)`

Comment: @VictorFreg could someone post an answer instead of comments?

Comment: ditto @rawr (answers instead of comments)

Answer (score 18):

Probably the most direct way to do this would be by capturing `"Avenue"` with `()` and then chopping off everything that appears after it:

```
a <- "45216 Walnut Avenue Mary's Bake Shop"
gsub("(Avenue).*", "\\1", a)
```

You'll get:

```
## [1] "45216 Walnut Avenue"
```